# Javascript for loop not waiting for all promise to execute

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous, react-native

I was having some problem with asynchronous call and for loop. What I am facing now is the for loop never waits for all the promise to complete before execute another round. My code skeleton as such:

```
 // removed code
```

Is there any way to do this such that the for loop will wait for all my promises done executing before executing another round?

Comment: I see a `resolve` inside `snapshot.forEach` ... which means you think you can resolve a Promise more than once

Comment: You can set a flag to check if all promises done and check this flag each time a promise done.

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry but what do you means? Is it wrong?

Comment: @huydq5000 flag as in boolean variable? Do you mind to provide me with some examples?

Comment: a forEach loop callback can be executed more than once ... however, a Promise can only be resolved once

Comment: `if all promises done` - there's only 2 promises in the code ... used in series

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah but that forEach will only return a row. All my other promises are done in the way like promiseMerchatKey, but then at the later part when I wanted to fetch the data, the data are too messy because the for loop never wait for the promise to finish execute before running another round

Comment: damn, sorry, didn't see the `for(let count = 0; count < 10; count++){` loop (had the code scrolled down)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it in a function that calls it self:

```
function ramdomMerch (index, maxIndex) {
  count = index;
  count++;
  if (count > maxIndex) {
    exit(); //This will end the loop as soon as it hits the maxIndex
  }


  // random select merchant
  let randomMerchantName = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      merchantName = branchlist[branchIndex].merchantName;
      resolve(merchantName);
  });


            let promiseMerchantKey = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              randomMerchantName.then((merchantName) => {
                firebase.database().ref('merchants').orderByChild('merchantName').equalTo(merchantName).once('value', function(snapshot) {
                  var merchantData = snapshot.val();
                    if (merchantData){
                      console.log('merchant exists');
                      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                        var item = childSnapshot.val();
                        item.key = childSnapshot.key;
                        resolve(item.key);
                      });
                    }else{
                      var merchantKey = firebase.database().ref('merchants').push({
                        merchantName : merchantName
                      }).getKey();

                      resolve(merchantKey);
                    }
                    ramdomMerch(count, maxIndex); // Here we simply call after finish the next "loop"
                });
              });
            });
}

randomMerch(1, 10); //We start it like an loop with the start and endIndex
```

A better way to work with promises is the [then](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) operator.
It would be a syntax like:

```
let promiseMerchantKey = new Promise(( ... 
promiseMerchantKey.then(function(value) {
   // Sucess, call next promise or next loop if it was the last
  }, function(reason) {
  // error
});
```

Comment: Sorry but the code above is randomly select merchant for 10 times right? Is there any way to force the for loop to finish execute whatever is inside before running another round? Because my situation is, I wanted to loop 10 times. For each time, I random generate category, merchant, branch and stuff. And within that loop, I need to get the randomly selected item and insert into firebase. After I finish insert all other part, then I run the second time.

Comment: I just copied your code inside of the function, it actually does nothing else than calling your code 10 times and waits until 1 run is finished before it calls the next one. You simply have to add the rest of your code and place the ramdomMerch(count, maxIndex); in your last promise. I think you want it in your insert promise

Comment: Sorry but the function is something like a for loop? So I just put all my promise in it, then at the last line I call the function again? Does it execute top down like Java?

Comment: It told me randomMerch is not a function. Do you have any idea why? I am writing in react native though

Comment: Yes it does, this way you can make sure that the promises are finished. It runs top -> down but can jump like in java. Thats why it would be also a good idea to seperate the promises in functions. Oh and sry I mostly write in typescript, so I forgot the function tag, will edit it :D

Comment: What I did was putting this: loopCounter = (index, maxIndex) => {} inside a .then() of another promise. Then I call it again at the last line when I execute the Touchable on click function

Comment: Yes, at the last promise inside of it you simply have to use .then again. .then((valueLastPromise) => {
   this.loopCounter(index, 10, namelist); 
});

Comment: Sorry I dont get it, my code now is running infinite loop. From the edited portion, promiseNameList is the first promise, I need to get that before all other promise in loopCounter function. As for the populate(), it is when text on click. Then inside my loopCounter function, at the last promise, I am calling the function again. But that gives me an infinite loop, any idea on which part I did wrongly?

Comment: I see sorry my bad, I am supposed to use count rather than index since I am incrementing count. Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: Happy I could help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to chain promises. You could do it like so:

```
//Just so we have a promise to start with for the chain.
let promiseMerchantKey = Promose.resolve();
for(let count = 0; count < 10; count++){

// random select category from list

// random select merchant
let randomMerchantName = promiseMerchantKey.then(()=>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        merchantName = branchlist[branchIndex].merchantName;
        resolve(merchantName);
    })
});

// create merchant
// check if merchant exists before add
promiseMerchantKey = randomMerchantName.then((marchantName)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        firebase.database().ref('merchants').orderByChild('merchantName').equalTo(merchantName).once('value', function(snapshot) {
                  var merchantData = snapshot.val();
                    if (merchantData){
                      console.log('merchant exists');
                      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                        var item = childSnapshot.val();
                        item.key = childSnapshot.key;
                        resolve(item.key);
                      });
                    }else{
                      var merchantKey = firebase.database().ref('merchants').push({
                        merchantName : merchantName
                      }).getKey();

                      resolve(merchantKey);
                    }
                });
              });
});


// all other promises to insert record into different child

}
```

Comment: Lets saymy promiseMerchantKey required from 3 different random promise, for instance, randomMerchantName, randomBranchAddress and randomBranchName, is there anyway to do so?

Comment: Lets say there is a way to do so yes. You can create the 3 promises, store them in array and return a Promise.all() which will make sure the 3 promises are done before continuing. But that's getting out of the scope of your first question.

Answer (score -1):

I write a prototype here, hope that help:

```
var donePromise = 0;
let n = 10;
for(let count = 0; count < n; count++){
    DoAPromisse(function() {
        donePromise++;

        if (donePromise == n) {
            //all promisesses done
        }
    });
}
```